# Can't Delete Contacts from Read-Only Accounts - Sync Adapter

Tags: android

I've created a custom SyncAdapter and given it the following XML:

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
          android:supportsUploading="true"
          android:userVisible="true"
          android:accountType="@string/authenticator_account_type"/>
```

Thousands of searches has led me to 'supportsUploading="true"' but this is definitely not the case - contacts are still being marked as read-only.

Since most of the documentation has a very "self-explanatory" vibe to it (Which is definitely not the case), I have no idea where to begin. Could someone please give me direction on this?

**Edit:** I even verified that the Account was in line with what Google has set for their accounts:

[image]

Comment: `Can't Delete Contacts from Read-Only Accounts` that kind of makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: The problem is there is nowhere that the account is explicitly defined as "read-only" in any of my code, and there is no such thing as an Account object being read-only from what I've found.

Comment: could you may be give a little more context? where does this message come from? where does it appear?

Comment: do you have the `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission?

Comment: I can't give too many details as it involves NDA hardware, but the message is coming from the contacts editor of the device. I do have WRITE_CONTACTS, the contacts are successfully being added from my sync adapter. I am able to delete the contacts on other devices, but I can also delete and edit Google contacts on this device and that shouldn't be touched by the device manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that the contacts information has to be set up in a very particular way. It includes having an XML file with a ContactsAccountType definition, a sync adapter XML file (sync-adapter) with android:supportsUploading="true" set... And there appears to be no one particular solution to this - if anything is not set up fully, the OS will treat ALL contacts as read-only.

I was able to copy the default contact from AOSP and modify it, removing things very slowly, one at a time (As like I mentioned, one wrong removal means read only) until I got it down to what was necessary.

The downside is, because both the OS as well as any function related will return that the contact is editable, it does not mean that the OS will allow it.

Comment: I have couple of questions.
1. Can you tell me how to define a contact structure in XML file.
2. Can i have a setting which can make contacts readable or writable dynamically ?